# How to find the space remaining in a text field?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following algorithm:

```
   if(textfield has no space left / full of characters till width)
        do something
   else
        keep adding characters
```

Now, the issue is I don't want the text field to be limited to X number of characters, but the actual width of the characters.

Any clues?

Comment: What do you mean by "the space", you want to add characters until a specific width is reached?

Comment: space = what exactly? Do enlighten us

Comment: I think he means the width of the characters - how much space they take on screen.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, by no space I mean. The total width of characters has reached width of textfield. An additional character would cause the field to wrap (if enabled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each change to the TextField, check the actual pixel width of the text using the `getLineMetrics(lineIndex:int)` method of the `TextField` class ([reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getLineMetrics%28%29)). If the actual text width is greater than the allowed width, remove characters from the end until it is narrow enough again.

Comment: If you are using flash.text.engine, you can also rely on TextLine.getAtomBounds if the metrics coming back from getLineMetrics are not proving accurate. Good luck.

Comment: I am back and I have news from the alien world. getLineMetrics not proving accurate.

Comment: You could try the `textWidth` property of the `TextField`, although I suspect it is just a convenience property returning he same value as `yourTextField.getLineMetrics(0).width`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to check the character count not including any whitespaces? In that case, this should be your answer..

```
var whitespace:RegExp = /(\t|\n|\s{2,})/g; 
var trimmedValue:String = txtFieldValue.replace(whitespace, "");

if(trimmedValue < maxCharacterCount) {
     do something
} else {
     keep adding chars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an input textfield with a maxChars property. Set the maxChars to say 12 and you can enter characters until the limit is reached.

Comment: He specifically stated he doesn't want to limit the characters, but the width. He's looking for character metrics to calculate when a textfield is filled visually.